# How can I split an integer into its component digits, and place each digit into a list?

Tags: python-3.x

This is the latest version of what I've tried so far.

I have two input n and k and anytime i reaches a number with k in it, it needs to print "boomboom"

```
n_print = list(range(1,n+1))
i = 0
for i in n_print:
if i == k:
        print("boom!")

####################### This part 
    elif i%k == 0 or k in list(str.split(repr(i))):     
##################### ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        print("boom-boom!")
    elif i != (n+1):
        print(i)
    else:
        break
```

so if k = 2 and n = 23, it should print "boom-boom!" for 12, 20, 21, 22, etc.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `str` and check for containment:

```
str(k) in str(i)
```

will test if the digits of `k` appear (consecutively, if more the one digit) in the digits of `i`.

So `k=2` and `i=23` will evaluate as true, as will `k=23` and `i=12345`. But `k=24` and `i=234` won't, because there is no substring of `24` in `"234"`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!!

It's not shown, but k's input is restricted to to 1-9.